# How to live stream audio from server in swift which has separate location url and resource url?

Tags: ios, swift, flash, audio, live-streaming

I am developing a music app from a third party API provider(www.mndigital.com). The API provider gives a 30 second demo for each song. The location of the demo app are given in this format

```
"SampleLocations": [
                {
                    "Location": "rtmp://mn-ecn-prd-rtmp.mndigital.com",
                    "Resource": "mp3:/spl/382/071/327/spl_024?48d882e51ff49ca3806e4b63d90b926556349db16cecf61947a8eb9a44f9bee3bf7d",
                    "Type": "s_mp3"
                },
                {
                    "Location": "rtmp://mn-ecn-prd-rtmp.mndigital.com",
                    "Resource": "mp4:/spl/382/071/327/spl_029.mp4?48d882e51ff49ca3806e4b63d90b926556349db16cecf61947a8eb9a44f9bee3bf7d",
                    "Type": "s_mp4"
                }
            ],
```

also the API provider says that the samples must be `streamed live` from server and `should not be saved locally`, in the terms and conditions.

After a few hours of searching i found that this format is for playing audio in a flash player. But in IOS flash player is not supported.

even for the `AVPlayer` to work we need only one url in the updated swift syntax

```
do {
    let url = "http://yourdomain.com/file.mp3"
    let fileURL = NSURL(string:url)
    let soundData = NSData(contentsOfURL:fileURL!)
    self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: soundData!)
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer.volume = 1.0
    audioPlayer.delegate = self
    audioPlayer.play()
} catch {
    print("Error getting the audio file")
}
```

So i don't know how to stream this kind of url in swift. Could anyone suggest a solution.

I am using swift 2.0 xcode 7.1.1 . My deployment target is IOS 8.0 and above

Comment: Since it's their API why not email **[mndigital.com](http://mndigital.com)**? Only they can tell you how to access the same MP3 without having to load it from an RTMP server. PS: RTMP does not always require Flash, even desktop players like VLC and Media Player Classic can load RTMP streams. You could get the MP3 if you knew the secret like those player's coders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long search i found that rtmp files cannot be played in apple devices as apple does not support flash payers. There is no way to play any data that provided by the URLs of these format.